# Register C functions in LUA in local lua_State, not global

Tags: c++, lua

I want to register C++ functions in local lua_state scope.

I have a c++ class that creates a lua_State in a new thread in the constructor and I then register functions from that class such as setX() that belongs to the class. This worked fine until I created multiple instances of that class, where I found that it registers the functions globally and not locally to the lua_state. I'm using LUA 5.3.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're asking, but I'll take a shot. States created by `lua_newstate` are completely independent. States created by `lua_newthread` share the global environment (and other things). You can't set a different environment for each thread state, but you can set an environment when loading Lua code -- when code is loaded (e.g. via `lua_load`), the environment (if any) is stored as the first upvalue (named `_ENV`). By default this is bound to the global environment, but it can be changed with `lua_setupvalue`.

Comment: @finis No, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358483/3677376).